# Results from mySQL using php show twice

Tags: php, mysql

I am connecting to my SQL server getting information from it using the following code:

```
if ($_POST['searchdb']) {
$searchi="".$_POST['search'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM consume WHERE  type LIKE '%{$searchi}%' OR description LIKE '%{$searchi}%'";
if($result= mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
      }
   } 
}
```

I have each value stored only once in my database but I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => RF Connector
    [Type] => RF Connector
    [1] => Male N Type Angle Cable Mtg.
    [Description] => Male N Type Angle Cable Mtg.
    [2] => Carousel
    [Location] => Carousel
    [3] => 2
    [Drawer] => 2
    [4] => Test
    [Supplier] => Test
    [5] => 12345678
    [Order Code] => 12345678
    [6] => 1
    [id] => 1
)
```

Why does the data seem to appear twice? Or is this normal?

Comment: Maybe i'm blind but i can't see the duplicated data here.

Comment: You should read this:http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, see here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
If you want numeric indices use this
`mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);`
and for associative indices use this
`mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

If you don't pass any parameter you will get an array containing both.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `mysqli_fetch_array` which puts two copies of the data into the result, once using the column number (starting from the left most column, numbered as 0) and once using the column's name.

You might find using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` to be more useful, you get one copy of the data and you get useful column names.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked a treat and you explained it really well for me to understad!

Answer (score 0):

this is because you used while mysqli_fetch_array($result)

```
                                    ^^^^^
```

it will give you both object and associative

use while mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

you will get associative values

Comment: both object and associative? do you mean numeric and are referring to the index types of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal when using `mysqli_fetch_array`

Replace it with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and you will get associative array which contains data only once or use `mysqli_fetch_row` to get enumerated array which also contains data only once.

source: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php